# PHP mail function works locally but not on the live site

Tags: php, email

I am using the PHP mail function to send an email (I know I should be using a library like Swift but this is a legacy app).

I have the following code - it definately works locally as I have installed the 'Test Mail Server Tool' to listen to all incoming emails on my localhost and it displays this as a pop-up, so I can be certain the current code does work from a code point of view.

However for some reason on the live server the email never seems to get delivered to the email address - can anyone suggest the most common problems for this?
Note - the email it is sending to on the live site belongs to a 'Google Apps' email address (not sure if this has any effect using Google).

Code..

```
        $to = 'admin@mysite.com';
        $subject = 'Customer Comment';
        $message['headers'] =   'From: ' . $comment_data['contact-email'] . "\r\n";
        $message['headers'] .=  'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        $m =    'Message Sent From: ' . $comment_data['contact-name']   . '<p />';
        $m .=   'Email Address: ' . $comment_data['contact-email']  . '<p />';
        $m .=   'Message Comment: ' . $comment_data['contact-comment']  . '<p />';
        $m .=   'Further Information Checkbox: ' . $site_info   . '<p />';
        $m .=   'Third Parties Checkbox: ' . $third_party   . '<p />';


        mail( $to, $subject, $m, $message['headers'] );
```

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder? What happens when you send a mail from the CLI?

Comment: One such issue is when you're on a shared server, sometimes the administrators can block the use of the `mail` function because someone else on your server has abused it, for spamming. Other than that check your logs for any errors.

Comment: Nothing in my Google Mail Spam folder - i'll check the logs also.

Comment: Quote: *"I know I should use a library but..."*  --- sorry, but I don't buy that excuse. Mail is a relatively self-contained part of any system; even on a legacy system, switching to a library like Swiftmail or phpMailer is relatively simple, and often easier than trying to fix the issues with using PHP's built-in `mail()` function.

Comment: nice email-header-injection example you've got there.

Comment: @Spudley I agree - I've gone the route of SwiftMailer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the logs have found the problem.. just need to fix it now - 
Application-specific password required - this is a problem with 2 step verification, just something for others to take note of when having problems with Google Apps accounts!